# java can not find symbol Objekt

Tags: java

I've got a problem with the default "Objekt" type in java. I thaught there was the possibility to name an attribute of a Class "Objekt", so it takes any kind of Objekt as allocation. The error is "can not find Symbol", heres the Code:

```
class List{

    private class Cell{
        Objekt value;
        Cell next;

        Cell (Objekt value, Cell next){

            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;

        }
    }

/* Following Methods that use other Classes, so the code becomes very hard to follow,
   so I'll leave them away because they dont seem to be the problem, as the error already
   shows up at the first usage of the Type "Objekt"*/

}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: This is `Object`, not `Objekt`. If you created an `Objekt` class, you have certainly missed to import it. But I really advise you to change its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not  `Objekt`. It should be  `Object`;

Answer (score 4):

`Objekt` should be `Object` (or possibly you've missed the import of your custom `Objekt`)

Answer (score 0):

Its `Object` not `Objekt`. I know there are few places where it may be written as 'Objekt', but talking about java programming.. it is spelled as 'Object'